# I can't import gensim package using Rodeo

Tags: python, rodeo

```
>>> import sys 
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Users\\adil\\AppData\\Local\\rodeo\\app2.5.2\\resources\\conda\\python.exe'
>>> ! conda install 'gensim'
>>> import gensim
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-ec15f3ffe0f1> in <module>()
----> 1 import gensim
ImportError: No module named 'gensim'
```

Comment: Please note: that **preview** window is meant so that you can **check** the formatting of your input before submitting it. I have **no** idea how to correctly format your code, but I am pretty sure you do not understand how your triple `> > >` chars show up in the end! So please step back and format your input so that we can actually help with your problem!

Comment: It's OK I solve it. Thanks

Comment: Then consider deleting your question. And for the future : format matters!